# Joomla Jupgrade installation error

Tags: joomla

I got this error when I try to install jupgrade package in joomla, please help me how to resolve this isse?

Error is :

> JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/es-ES.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'es-ES' has not been installed or does not exist.
>
> JInstaller::install: The language file 'languages/it-IT.com_jupgrade.ini' could not be installed because the Administrator language package for 'it-IT' has not been installed or does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the language package http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/translations-for-joomla